# Is $\mathcal{T}$ a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $V_a=(a,+\infty)$, $F_a=[a,+\infty)$.

1.Prove that $\mathcal{T}=\left\lbrace \emptyset,\mathbb{R},V_a:a\in\mathbb{R}\right\rbrace$ is a topology over $\mathbb{R}$.

2.Is $\mathcal{T'}=\left\lbrace \mathbb{\emptyset}, \mathbb{R}, F_a:a \in \mathbb{R}\right\rbrace$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

For question 1, I have already proved that $\emptyset,\mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{T}$ and if $G_1,G_2 \in \mathcal{T} $ then $G_1 \cap G_2 \in \mathcal{T}$ but I stuck at the codition about the union because it has so many cases which made me lost.

For question 2, I prove it is a topo the same as question 1, but I think it's wrong, I think it is not a topology ?

Can you help me with 2 these questions please ?

Comment: By "topo" you mean topology right?

Comment: @desiigner Yes it is

Comment: Union of $V_{\a}$ are easy.  $V_a \cup V_b = V_{min(a,b)}$. Any finite union  will be $\cup_{a_i} V_{a_i} = V_{\min a_i}$.  Might take a bit of hand waving by is $E\subset \mathbb R$ and bounded below then $\cup_{a\in E} V_a = V_{\inf E}$ and if $E$ is not bounded below $\cup_{a\in E} V_a = \mathbb R$.

Comment: You may also consider $\mathcal{T}'' = \{∅, \mathbb{R}, V_a, F_a: a ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the unions, let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ nonempty. We have

$$\bigcup_{a \in A} V_a = \begin{cases} (\inf A, +\infty), &\text{ if $A$ is bounded from below}\\
\mathbb{R}, &\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$
so $\bigcup_{a \in A} V_a \in \mathcal{T}$. If we add $\emptyset$ to this union it remains the same, and if we add $\mathbb{R}$ the result is $\mathbb{R}$. In any case, $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under unions.

$\mathcal{T'}$ is not a topology since
$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_{1/n} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\frac1n,+\infty\right) = (0,+\infty) \notin \mathcal{T}'$$
so $\mathcal{T}'$ is not closed under unions.

Answer (score 1):

For question $1$ assume we have a non empty set $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. We want to prove that $\cup_{a\in I} V_a\in\mathcal{T}$. Let $b=\inf I$. If $b=-\infty$ then $\cup_{a\in I} V_a=\mathbb{R}\in\mathcal{T}$. If $b>-\infty$ then you can check that $\cup_{a\in I} V_a=V_b\in\mathcal{T}$.

As for question $2$-it is not a topology.Take the set $I=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $\cup_{a\in I}F_a=(0,\infty)\notin\mathcal{T'}$.

Answer (score 1):

Crutch:  In the "usual" metric topology the sets $(a,\infty)$ are open so its *reasonable* to think this will be compatible with being open.  In the "usual" $[a,\infty)$ are closed so that's a big red flag this will never work.

But... crutches are bad; dont use them.

But you can use them as motivation for insight.

The *reason* any union of open intervals fits into the topology of disjoint union of open intervals is because if any $(a_i, b_i)$ intervals overlap their union is $(\inf a_i, \sup b_i)$ an open interval.

For $V_a$ it's even easier.  Let $E\subset \mathbb R$.  If $x \le \inf E$ then there is no $a\in E$ so that $a < x$ so $x \in (a,\infty)=V_a$ for any $a\in E$ so $x \not \in \cup_{e\in E} V_e$.

And if $x > \inf E$ there is an $a\in E$ so that $a < x$ and $x\in(a,\infty)=V_a \subset \cup_{e\in E}V_e$.  So $\cup_{e\in E}V_e = (\inf E,\infty) \in \mathcal {T}$.

But what if $E$ isn't bounded below?  Well, then for all $x \in \mathbb R$ there is an $a\in E$ so that $a <x$ and $x \in V_a\subset\cup_{e\in E}V_e$ and so $\cup_{e\in E}V_e =\mathbb R \in \mathcal{T}$.

And the reason we can't do the same for closed intervals is because it is possible a set of closed intervals $[a_i, b_i]$ will be such that $\inf a_i$ exists (or $\sup b_i$) but isn't one of the $a_i$ and so $\inf a_i \not \in \cup [a_i, b_i]$ and the union will have an "open" not "closed" endpoint.

The same is true for unions of $F_a$.  If $E$ is a set that is bounded below but $\inf E \not \in E$ then for any $x \le \inf E$ we have $x$ is not in any $F_a$.  But if $x > \inf E$ there is an $a< x$ so $x \in F_a$.  So $\cup_{e\in E}F_e = (\inf E, \infty) \not \in \mathcal {T'}$.

So $\mathcal{T'}$ is not a topology.

Similar logic for intersections.

The reason we need a *finite* intersection of open intervals is that if you have an *infinite* intersections of $(a_i, b_i)$ and all $a_i < \sup a_i$ then the $\sup a_i$ is in every interval but nothing smaller is.  So $\sup a_i$ would be a "closed" endpoint.

But if we have finite intersection then the $a_i$ are finite and a max exist and it is one of the $a_i$ and we have an open interval.

So if $E$ is a finite set then $\max E$ exist and $\max E \in E$.  If $x \le \max E$ then $x \not \in (\max E, \infty) =V_{\max E}$ so $x \not \in \cap_{e\in E}V_e$.  But if $x > \max E$ then $x > e$ for all $e \in E$ and $x \in (e,\infty)$.  So $\cap_{e\in E}V_e = (\max E,\infty)\in \mathcal {T}$.

So $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology.

(We can note, but we don't have to, that if $E$ is infinite and bounded above by $\sup E$ and $\sup E \not \in E$ then we'd have $\cap_{e\in E}V_e = [\max E,\infty)\not \in \mathcal {T}$.  But infinite intersections don't count.

We've already shown $\mathcal{T'}$ is not a topology.  But to hone our skills we can try to calculate what $\cap_{e\in E} F_e$ are.

It actually doesn't matter whether $E$ is finite or not.

If $E$ is bounded above then for any $x \ge \sup E$ we have $x \in [e\infty)$ for all $e \in E$ so $x \in \cap_{e\in E} F_e$.  If $x < \sup E$ then there is an $a > x$ and $x \not \in F_a$ so $x \not \in \cap_{e\in E} F_e$.  So $\cap_{e\in E} F_e = [\sup E, \infty)\in \mathcal {T'}$.

If $E$ is not bounded above then for any $x$ there is an $a \in E$ so that $a > x$ and $x \in \in F_a$  so $\cap_{e\in E} F_e = \emptyset \in \mathcal{T'}$.

So $\mathcal{T'}$ would satisfy the intersection condition.  But it already failed the union condition.